# Executing an action at a specific time in C

Tags: c, linux

I have a while loop that decodes a video file by retrieving each frame, so something like this:

```
while (get_frame(codec_ctx, format_ctx, video_stream, frame) != 0) {
      ...
 }
```

Now, once a frame is retrieved, it needs to be drawn onto the screen at a certain point in the future (according to the frame's timestamp.) How could this be implemented? Is there some means by which I can set a callback to be executed at a specific time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push a (frame, time) pair onto a queue, then have a separate thread execute the following algorithm:

```
loop {
    time, frame = pop(queue);
    wait_until(time);
    display(frame);
}
```

where `pop` waits for an item to be pushed onto the queue if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select(2)` to wait until you need to draw the frame (or until you need to do something else, indicated by one of the FDs passed to `select()` being poked).

Comment: I would suggest rather using `poll` which I feel is more modern than `select`